# wcf service bad request 400 streaming

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming

I am developing a wcf service, to upload xml files to a storage database,
for that reason i am ziping the file, saving it to a memorystream and passing it to the service with PushData(Stream as MemoryStream)
Unfortunatly i cant get it to work. It seems i have some configuration missing, or wrong.
I host the service on an iis 8.0 as self hosted in storageservice.svc
The Error Msg is: 400 bad request

here are my config files

client side app config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IStorageService"     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"  receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
            <security mode="None"/>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://10.5.1.6:8001/StorageService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IStorageService"
           name="BasicHttpBinding" contract="StorageService.IStorageService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

server side web config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Namespace.StorageService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Namespace.IStorageService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://10.5.1.6:8001/" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://10.5.1.6:10001/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>       
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
     <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"  receiveTimeout="00:10:00" >
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
<protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I really need help, tried 3 days to figure it out ... and all the buffersizes didnt help anything

Solutions Tried:

1. Add readerquotas element in binding
2. Use Mtom messageEncoding
3. Enable Tracing (unfortunatly didn't do anything)

EDIT: Client Method

```
  Using client As New StorageService.StorageServiceClient
            client.Open()
            Dim helper As CirrostratusHelper = New CirrostratusHelper
            Dim data As CirrostratusStorage = helper.GenerateData()
            Dim gdata = data.GenerateData
            For Each item In gdata
                Try
                    Dim memorystream As New MemoryStream
                    Dim databasedaata As ZipArchive = item.Value.DatabaseData
                    databasedaata.Save(memorystream)
                    memorystream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                  ' this method produces the bad exception '
                    client.PushData(memorystream)
                Catch ex As Exception                  
                    Dim test = ex.Message & ex.StackTrace
                End Try
            Next
            client.Close()
        End Using
```

Servive Method:

```
   Public Function PushData(DataStream As Stream) As Boolean Implements IStorageService.PushData
      Const buffersize As Integer = 2048
            Dim buffer(buffersize) As Byte
            Dim bytesread As Integer = bytesread = DataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize)
            Dim DataMemoryStream As New MemoryStream
            While bytesread > 0
                bytesread = DataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize)
                DataMemoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffersize)
            End While
            DataMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Dim zip As ZipArchive = ZipArchive.Read(DataMemoryStream)
              '...'
    end function
```

Comment: additional info:the file i like to send is ~ 20 MB

Comment: I don't see a problem with the config. What's the function look like that's streaming the xml up?

Comment: Another question ... if you're uploading from a client to a storage server, why are you streaming instead of buffering? The code involved in streaming is quite a bit more complicated than for buffering.

Comment: i read some blogs about to use streaming for huge data, we have sometimes like 3 gb data to send...

Comment: OK, yeah, with 3 gb you'd probably want to stream simply because you'd probably run out of memory before the whole thing buffered. Post the code you're using to upload the stream so we can have a look.

Comment: already edited my original entry... but that code is no magic... as you see..

Comment: I don't see a problem there ... sorry, I wish I could be more help.

Comment: thanks for looking over the problem, can you think of any issues with iis 8.0? or probably some other connections issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,
it was about the naming for the binding and i forgot to make the endpoint use the bindingconfiguration

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding_Storage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"  receiveTimeout="00:10:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
 <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_Storage" contract="DynaMed.IStorageService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
```